# Trying to get property 'description' of non-object Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I am new to Laravel and I am currently trying to make a Todos application. However, when I try to read from the model and show it in the Blade file, this error appears:

> "Trying to get property 'description' of non-object"

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/{todo}', 'TodosController@show');
```

**TodosController.php**

```
public function show($todoId){
    $todos = Todo::find($todoId);

    return view('todos.show', compact('todos'));
}
```

**show.blade.php**

```
 @foreach ($todos as $todo)
     <li class="list-group-item">
         {{ $todo->description }}
     </li>
 @endforeach
```

The error is in `{{ $todo->description }}`

I had seen similar questions but I could not understand therefore please help me. I want to know why is this error occurring and how can I solve it?

Comment: do you want to get a list of $todos in foreach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public function show($todoId){
        $todos = Todo::where('id', $todoId)->get();
        return view('todos.show', compact('todos'));
    }
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks! But, I could not still figure out why was the error occurring. Could you please tell me?

Comment: you get id = Your find id not directly so

Comment: please select this answer if its help for you Thank you AND give upvote THANK YOU.

Comment: I have done it. But since I have less reputation in stackoverflow it doesn't display in mine. It might have shown in yours.

Comment: Ok can you please give upvote this answer thank you..if you able..

Answer (score 3):

```
$todos = Todo::find($todoId);
```

will get you a single instance of a `Todo`. In your view you are looping through what looks like you are expecting an array or collection of `Todos`

You can either remove the foreach loop in your view or change your `Todo` query to:

```
$todos = Todo::where('id', $todoId)->get()
```

This will give you a single `Todo` wrapped in a collection allowing your loop to get the single `Todo` instance in the collection.

The problem is that when you pass an instance of a model to a loop it starts looping through the properties. You're then trying to get the property on another property which doesn't exist.
You need to pass an array or collection to the loop so each item is an instance with valid properties.

It might be helpful to do a dump to see the results of the methods available for getting data

```
dump(
    Todo::all(),
    Todo::where('id', $todoId)->get(),
    Todo::find($todoId)
);
```

You'll see the first two return collections which work when you pass then to your foreach.
The second returns an instance of `Todo` which can be passed to your loop but the loop then pulls properties from the instance instead if instances form the collection. You want the latter.

Comment: Thank you! It is working now. I have done the same for name and it worked but why is it not working for description?

Comment: I would need to see what you did for name. I suspect that you were not looping through items to show the name, therefore you were not trying to access the name property on  the first property of your instance

Comment: **TodosController.php**
 `public function index(){
        $todos = Todo::all();
        return view('todos.index',compact('todos'));
        
    }`

**show.blade.php**
`@foreach ($todos as $todo)
                <li class="list-group-item">
                    {{ $todo->name }}
                </li>
                @endforeach`

Comment: Okay, you've called `Todo::all()` in this example which returns a collection of `Todos` so when you pass it to the loop each item in the loop has properties. In your OP you only have a single instance of a `Todo` that you pass to the loop

Comment: It might be helpful to dump the results of `Todo::all()`, `Todo::where('id', $todoId)->get()` and `Todo::find($todoId)` so you can see the difference in the way the data is returned

Answer (score 0):

## TodosController.php

```
    public function show($todoId){
    $todos = Todo::find($todoId)->get()->first();
    return view('todos.show', compact('todos'));
}
```

## show.blade.php

```
    <li class="list-group-item">
       {{ $todos['description'] }}
    </li>
```

> no need to use foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct but also add a model name like

```
public function show(Todo $todoId){
    $todos = Todo::find($todoId);

    return view('todos.show', compact('todos'));
}
```

This is the laravel default that used if you are on the same controller